# GROUP BY - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I group column USER_TYPE and ROLE DESCRIPTION

```
id  USER_NAME   USER_TYPE   ROLE_DESCRIPTION
40406   AJ     PROGRAMMER2  Reversal
40406   AJ     PROGRAMMER2  Requester
40406   AJ     PROGRAMMER2  Programmer
40406   AJ     REQUESTER    Reversal
40406   AJ     REQUESTER    Requester
40406   AJ     REQUESTER    Programmer
```

Currently I have this query but it gives me error "Column 'USERS.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.":

```
select U.id,
        U.USER_NAME,
        UT.USER_TYPE,
        R.ROLE_DESCRIPTION
 from USERS U

 left join USERS_USER_TYPE UUT on U.id = UUT.CON_ID
 left join USER_TYPE UT on UUT.USER_TYPE_ID = UT.ID

 left join USER_ROLE UR on U.id = UR.CON_ID
 left join ROLES R on UR.ROLE_ID = R.ID

 where U.id = 40406
 group by UT.ID
```

Expected Output:

```
id  USER_NAME   USER_TYPE   ROLE_DESCRIPTION
40406   AJ     PROGRAMMER2  Reversal
40406   AJ     REQUESTER    Requester
40406   AJ     NULL         Programmer
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The error is clear. You can't use columns that *aren't* in the `GROUP BY` clause without applying an aggregate function. A user may have many roles but you requested *one* row only for each `ID`. Which role should be displayed?

Comment: BTW are you sure you want *GROUP BY*? You can't *sum* or *average* roles or names. You can concatenate the values with `STRING_AGG` or return the minimum, maximum value with `MIN` or `MAX`. What output do you want to produce?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to remove the duplicate data.

Comment: Duplicate data means on which Column?

Comment: @ShyamVemula for USER_TYPE and ROLE_DESCRIPTION. is that possible?

Comment: Show us the output you want.  You are not making sense.

Comment: Possible..I will give ans.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen already update the question.

Comment: OK, now explain the logic behind this output.  How do we decide which rows are removed?

Comment: @AJMoquete How `User_Type` is `NULL` For last row in Expected result.

Comment: `SQL Server` is relational database and in your expected output there is no relationship between `USER_TYPE` and `ROLE_DESCRIPTION` columns. Please store both columns in different tables if there is no relation between them.

Comment: @AJMoquete the result you posted comes from a simple JOIN. You don't need GROUP BY to produce it. If you have random data it's because your joins are probably wrong and return all combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-relational data representation, I will add random number to distinct data of each column and then combine these columns on the basis of this random number. I have use `DENSE_RANk` function to provide random numbering to distinct data of column. My solution to this task is -

```
;with cte as
(
    select U.id,
        U.USER_NAME,
        UT.USER_TYPE,
        R.ROLE_DESCRIPTION
    from USERS U
    left join USERS_USER_TYPE UUT on U.id = UUT.CON_ID
    left join USER_TYPE UT on UUT.USER_TYPE_ID = UT.ID
    left join USER_ROLE UR on U.id = UR.CON_ID
    left join ROLES R on UR.ROLE_ID = R.ID
    where U.id = 40406
    group by UT.ID
)
select
    isnull(x.id, y.id) as id,
    isnull(x.USER_NAME, y.USER_NAME) as user_name,
    x.USER_TYPE,
    y.ROLE_DESCRIPTION
from
    (select distinct
        dense_rank() over (order by user_type) as indexid,
        id, User_name, user_type
        from cte) as x
    full join
    (select distinct
        dense_rank() over (order by role_description) as indexid,
        id, User_name, ROLE_DESCRIPTION
        from cte) as y
    on y.indexid = x.indexid
```

OUTPUT -

```
id      USER_NAME   USER_TYPE   ROLE_DESCRIPTION
40406   AJ          PROGRAMMER2 Programmer
40406   AJ          REQUESTER   Requester
40406   AJ          NULL        Reversal
```

Comment: How can I use my tables instead of temporary table?

Comment: Replace @temp_tbl with your table name.

Comment: it gives me error "Invalid column name 'User_name'." when I used my tables.

Comment: Please paste your modified query.

Comment: declare @USERS table (id int, USER_NAME varchar(100), USER_TYPE varchar(100), ROLE_DESCRIPTION varchar(100))

select
    isnull(x.id, y.id) as id,
    isnull(x.USER_NAME, y.USER_NAME) as user_name,
    x.USER_TYPE,
    y.ROLE_DESCRIPTION
from
    (select distinct
        dense_rank() over (order by user_type) as indexid,
        id, User_name, user_type
        from USER_TYPE) as x
    full join
    (select distinct
        dense_rank() over (order by role_description) as indexid,
        id, User_name, ROLE_DESCRIPTION
        from ROLES) as y
    on y.indexid = x.indexid

Comment: @AJMoquete, I have updated my answer and use your SQL query inside CTE. Please check.